# Prove that for the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_5 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$, the homomorphism $\alpha$ is trivial

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, semidirect-product, direct-product

Suppose $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \rtimes_\alpha \mathbb{Z}_3$ with respect  to a homomorphism $\alpha:\mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$. Show that $\alpha$ is trivial and that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Is $G$ a cyclic group?

My proof:

Let $([a]_5, [b]_3), ([c]_5, [d]_3) \in \mathbb{Z}_5 \rtimes_\alpha \mathbb{Z}_3$

The semidirect product gives

$$([a]_5, [b]_3) ([c]_5, [d]_3) = ([a]_5 \alpha_{[b]_3}([c]_5), [b]_3[d]_3)$$
$$= ([a]_5 ([b]_3 [c]_5 [b]_3^{-1}), [b]_3 [d]_3)$$
$$= ([a]_5[c]_5[b]_3[b]_3^{-1}, [b]_3 [d]_3)$$
$$= ([a]_5[c]_5, [b]_3[d]_3)$$
$$= \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$$

the definition of the regular direct product.

In the middle of the calculations we see that the inner automorphism is trivial always since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is abelian.

Therefore $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Finally it is cyclic since $\mathrm{gcd}(5,3) = 1$ so $5$ and $3$ are coprime. Therefore the direct product is cyclic

Comment: Do you know what $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_5)$ is? If you know it is $\mathbb Z_4,$ you are practically done.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to use anything about the numbers $3$ and $5$ other than being coprime. Since the statement would be false if one replaced $5$ by $7$, that indicates that there is a major error.

Comment: Is it the case that $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n) = \mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$ always?

Comment: No, that is not always the case. It will be of order $\varphi(n)$ and not in general be cyclic (since it will be isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$).

Comment: The problem in the proof is that $\varphi$ is a general automorphism (inner automorphism doesn't make sense, as those groups are not subgroups of each other).

Comment: Do I need to find then an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ such that $\varphi([k]_5)^3 = [k]_5$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your reasoning is that you assume $\alpha$ must be
$$\alpha: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5): [b]_3 \mapsto \iota_{[b]_3},$$
with
$$\iota_{[b]_3}: \mathbb{Z}_5 \to \mathbb{Z}_5: [c]_5 \mapsto [b]_3[c]_5 [b]_3^{-1}.$$

This "inner automorphism" doesn't make any sense, because you are trying to multiply elements that belong to different groups!

Let us first try to calculate what "known group" $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ is isomorphic to, and then try to construct a morphism $\alpha: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is cyclic and generated by $[1]_5$, any automorphism $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ is determined completely by the value of $\varphi([1]_5)$. There are $5$ possible values of $\varphi([1]_5)$. I'll leave it to you to prove that $\varphi([1]_5) = [0]_5$ will not produce an automorphism, and the other four possibilities will form a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$. Thus $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$.

So we can see $\alpha$ as a morphism 
$$\alpha: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_4.$$
For the same reason as mentioned above, $\alpha$ is completely determined by the value of $\alpha([1]_3)$. Again, I'll leave it up to you to show the only possible $\alpha$ is
$$\alpha: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_4: [b]_3 \mapsto [0]_4,$$
which translates to
$$\alpha: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5): [b]_3 \mapsto \operatorname{id}.$$

Comment: $\varphi([1]_5)^k = [k0]_4 \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, the reason it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is because every element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ except for $[0]_5$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Why do those other 4 possibilities form a separate group (in this case isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$?) How can I use this technique for finding automorphisms with different groups (e.g. $D_n, S_n$)

Comment: You indeed need that every non-identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ generates the entire group. You need this to show that the *homomorphisms* defined by $\varphi([1]_5) = [1]_5$, $\varphi([1]_5) = [2]_5$, ... are actually *automorphisms*, whereas the homomorphism defined by $\varphi([1]_5) = [0]_5$ is not an automorphism.

Comment: At this point, you have calculated all automorphisms, which form a group under composition. If this is unclear to you, I'm sure you can find a proof somewhere on MSE. To check the automorphism group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ in this situation, I suggest you write down the Cayley table and compare to groups you know. This also works for other groups, provided they do not contain too many elements of course.

Answer (score 0):

It needn't to know that $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_p)\cong\Bbb Z_{p-1}$ (not even that $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_p)\right|=p-1$).

If a group $G$ acts on another group $H$ (by automorphisms), then:
$$\operatorname{Fix}(g)\le H, \forall g\in G \tag 1$$
where $\operatorname{Fix}(g):=\{h\in H\mid \phi_g(h)=h\}$, being $\phi\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ the action. In fact, for every $g\in G$, $\phi_g(1_H)=1_H$, whence $1_H\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)\ne\emptyset$; moreover, by definition, $\operatorname{Fix}(g)\subseteq H$; finally, for every $g\in G$ and $h_1,h_2\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)$, $\phi_g(h_1h_2^{-1})=$ $\phi_g(h_1)\phi_g(h_2^{-1})=$ $\phi_g(h_1)\phi_g(h_2)^{-1}=$ $h_1h_2^{-1}$, whence $h_1h_2^{-1}\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)$.

If $G$ and $H$ are both finite, say $G=\{g_1,\dots,g_{|G|}\}$ and $H=\{h_1,\dots,h_{|H|}\}$, then:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{|H|}\left|\operatorname{Stab}(h_i)\right|=\sum_{j=1}^{|G|}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g_j)\right| \tag 2$$
and (from Burnside's Lemma):
$$|G|\text{ divides } \sum_{j=1}^{|G|}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g_j)\right| \tag 3$$
where now the terms in the RHS of $(2)$ and in $(3)$ all divide $|H|$ (Lagrange).

In particular, take $G=\Bbb Z_p$ and $H=\Bbb Z_q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. If a nontrivial homomorphism $\phi$ exists, then $\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g_{\bar j})\right|=1$ and $\left|\operatorname{Stab}(h_{\bar i})\right|=1$, for some $\bar j\in \{1,\dots,p\}$, $\bar i\in\{1,\dots,q\}$. Then $(2)$ and $(3)$ yield:
\begin{cases}
k+(q-k)p=l+(p-l)q \\
p\mid pq-l(q-1) \\
\end{cases}
and rearranging:
\begin{cases}
k(p-1)=l(q-1) \\
p\mid pq-l(q-1) \\
\tag 4
\end{cases}
for some $1\le k\le q$ and $1\le l\le p$. Now, **if $\bf{p\nmid q-1}$** (in particular if $p>q$), then from $(4.2)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&p\mid l \Longrightarrow\\
&\bf{l=p}\stackrel{(4.1)}{\Longrightarrow}\\
&k(p-1)=p(q-1)\Longrightarrow\\
&k=\frac{p}{p-1}(q-1)>q-1\Longrightarrow\\
&\bf{k=q}\\
\end{alignat}
But $(k,l)=(q,p)$ is not a solution of $(4.1)$, and hence there isn't any nontrivial homomorphism $\phi\colon \Bbb Z_p\to\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_q)$, namely $\Bbb Z_p\ltimes\Bbb Z_q=$ $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_q$. Your case is just the particular one for $p=3$, $q=5$, as $3\nmid 5-1$.